# Implicit function theorem implies per image is a smooth manifold with boundary

Tags: differential-geometry

I have a question. If $f:M\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a function in a manifold. If $a$ is not a critical value of $f$. Then how we know from implicit function theorem that $\{x\in M; f(x)\leq a\}$ is a smooth manifold with boundary? I think I know the level set of a is a smooth sub manifold of $M$. Thanks for any help!

Comment: The open set $\{x \in M :  f(x) < a\}$ is trivially an $n$-manifold.   So you just need to build charts $\phi:U \to H^n$ about points $p$ where $f(p)=a.$   The "Submersion Theorem" is a generalization of the ImpFcn Theorem, and locally,  you may view $f:M \to \mathbb{R}$ a projection $(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n) \to  x_1.$   Use this fact to get your chart $\phi.$

Comment: I think your first sentence gives some hint to my question. But I don't get how we regard f as a projection locally? Thanks!

Comment: For each $p$ where $f(p)=a,$  There exists  a smooth chart $(U_p,\phi)$ with $\phi(p)=0$ and $f \circ \phi^{-1} = \pi,$  where $\pi:\mathbb{R^n} \to \mathbb{R}$ is the projection onto the first coordinate.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation!

Comment: @mattbiesecker , why is $\{x \in M :  f(x) < a\}$ an $n$-manifold? Can you explain it?

Comment: @serge its the preimage of an open set and open subsets are submanifolds